# What happens if we block ICMP from accessing our internal network from the outside?

Tags: firewalls

What are the effects if we block ICMP from outside to the inside network, and what are the impacts on the organization?

Comment: does ICMP reach the inside network? I'm not sure that it does.

Comment: is this a security question? if so, what are the security aspects to the question?